# Correct Understanding of Stative Verb in Masu Stem + いく・ゆく

Tags: nuances

死にいく
死にゆく
These more of 'resultative verbs' that when put into ている form mean a resultant state, like how 死んでいる means dead not dying, when put into にいく・にゆく form, do they mean something different that verbs that ている form can represent an ongoing action.

For example, 食べに行く is to go to eat, but is verbs of the type 死ぬ is different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the equivalent of 死ぬ to 食べに行く is 死に**に**行く, which means *to go to somewhere where the subject would die (e.g., to a war)*. As a pattern, it is 'masu-stem + に + 行く'.

The pattern for 死にゆく is 'masu-stem + 行く', where 行く is read ゆく in most cases. The reading is just for the ease of pronunciation, but 死にいく sounds uncommon to me. Other examples would be 消えゆく(disappearing),滅びゆく(dismantling) etc.

---

From [here](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13214600613) (emphasis added)

> ゆく【行く・往く】（ 動カ五［四］ ）
> 〔同義の語に「いく」があり、上代から併用される。「ゆく」と「いく」は一般に同じ語の少し異なった語形とうけとられており、本辞典では、この「ゆく」の項で両方あわせて記述する〕
>
> (1) 現代語では、**「いく」にくらべ、「ゆく」の方がより文章語的な感じをもつ。** (2) 原則として「ゆく」「いく」どちらの形も使えるが、「立ちゆく」「亡びゆく」「更けゆく」「消えゆく」、「ゆくえ」「ゆく末」「ゆくて」「ゆく春」「ゆくゆく（は）」などは**普通、「いく」の形をとらない。** (3) 連用形の音便形は、現代語では「いく」の「いっ（て）」「いっ（た）」の形しか用いられない。ただし古くは「ゆく」にも音便形として「ゆい（て）」があった。 (4) 平安鎌倉時代の漢文訓読では「いく」の例はまれで、ほとんど「ゆく」が用いられた〕

Comment: If I understand right, you're saying that:
Shini ni Iku -> Go to die
Shini ni Yuku -> Go to die
Shini yuku -> Dying
Shini Iku -> Dying

So if you put the Ni particle then it means to go to do verb.
If you don't put the Ni particle, then it means going towards that verb as in disappearing, dying, etc?

Comment: @Catdog Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you so much